# How to remove a line break of texarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textarea, submit

currently i am working on a forum for my website. In one section I have a form that contains a textarea like this

```
<textarea id="answer" class="field" onKeyPress="handleKeyPress(event)"></textarea>
```

Then I use the following Javascript function

```
function handleKeyPress(e){
    var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key==13 && e.shiftKey)
    {
        //Don't do anything
    }
    else if(key==13){
        forum_answer_submit();
    }
}
```

to submit the form. All that works just fine except for one issue. If a user clicks the enter button, I will revieve the content of the textarea including the new line which will be empty ( from pressing the enter button ). On top of that since all of that is handled through javascript the site doesn't refresh so there will be an empty line in the textarea.
Is there any way for me to remove the empty line from the texarea and from the content of the string in javascript?

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault();` right above your `forum_answer_submit();`

Comment: handle keydown instead and prevent the event from bubbling up if it is the enter key.

Comment: I just changed it to "onKeyUp" and it works fine. The only issue i have now is that there will be an empty line stored in the db because of the enter button. Can i remove the last line in Javascript somehow?